# How can I find out the status/content/value of a variabe

Tags: python, websocket, try-catch

I catch data by a websocket. Here becoming body, meta inside body, frame_port inside meta. But not every meta has a frame_port.

When I do

```
frameport = response["body"]["meta"]["frame_port"]
```

I become frameport if there is a frameport

Then I tried to set frameport = 1 if there is no frame_port in meta, but here I need help.

If I do the following, I get no print at all, not before and not after the try/excpet block. so this try/excpet doesnt work. any idea how to check if there is a frame_port inside meta and if not set to 0?

```
try:
   frameport
except NameError:
   print("no frameport defined")
   frameport = 1
print("frameport is:" (frameport))
```

Comment: `"some_key" in some_dict` returns a `bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictionary's `get` with default:

```
frameport = response["body"]["meta"].get("frame_port", 1)
```

Note that this only covers case when the key does not exist. If it does, but contains value you don't want, let's say `None` and 0, that value needs to be dealt with separately:

```
frameport = response["body"]["meta"].get("frame_port", 1)
if frameport is None or frameport == 0:
    frameport = 1
```

As far your try/catch attempt, it does not work because this line:

```
frameport
```

won't throw any exceptions no matter what value `frameport` holds

Answer (score 1):

`get` seems like it would be handy for what you're trying to do:

```
frameport = response["body"]["meta"].get("frame_port", 1)
```

If there isn't a key `"frame_port"` then the `frameport` variable will be set to 1.